# Requiring named arguments in Boost Python

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost-python

I'm trying to make Boost Python require that arguments are named by the caller.

As Python 3 implements [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/), I can easily do that in pure Python:

```
def foo(*, name=None, age=None):
    print("%s is %d years" % (name, age))
```

The above means that:

```
foo(name="Joe", age=33) # works
foo(age=33, name="Joe") # works
foo("Joe", 33) # raises TypeError
```

However, this isn't straight-forward in Boost Python. The following isn't even close:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>

void foo(const std::string& name, int age)
{
  printf("%s is %d years\n", name.c_str(), age);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  def("foo", foo, (arg("name"), arg("age")));
}
```

While this works with named arguments, they are not required, so I can still do `foo("Joe", 33)`.

I've tried:

- Using [raw_function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/raw_function.html), but that requires me to have a C++ signature of `(boost::python::tuple, boost::python::dict)`.
- Exposing the function with `(arg("*"), arg("name")="...", arg("age")=-1)`, but that doesn't compile.

Is it possible at all to expose `foo` through Boost Python as described in the top Python example?

Comment: What's wrong with creating a wrapper for your function to be used with raw_function?

Comment: Fair point, but in my case I need to call an existing C++ API, and I'd rather not have to unpack variables, check their types, extract their values and then call another function in `foo`. It's just a lot of work in my case.